# glassfish before tomcat

Tags: login, startup, tomcat, runlevel, glassfish

i have used this to install tomcat http://diegobenna.blogspot.com/2011/01/install-tomcat-7-in-ubuntu-1010.html

and 
this to install http://www.silvatechsolutions.com/tech-tips/glassfish-ubuntu-12-04-ubber-quick-install-guide/

i know about update-rc.d command for priority boot from here http://www.pathbreak.com/blog/ubuntu-startup-init-scripts-runlevels-upstart-jobs-explained
and here http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-managing-services-with-update-rc-d/

here are my planed boot up

1. other bootup processes
2. ....
3. MySql server
4. Apache server
5. Glassfish
6. Tomcat
7. User Login aka gnome or ubuntu unity

Here is the problem when i run

> sudo find /etc/rc* -iname "*mysql*"

no result

> sudo find /etc/rc* -iname "*gnome*"

no result

> sudo find /etc/rc* -iname "*unity*"

no result

> sudo find /etc/rc* -iname "*apache*"

/etc/rc0.d/K09apache2

/etc/rc1.d/K09apache2

/etc/rc2.d/S91apache2

/etc/rc3.d/S91apache2

/etc/rc4.d/S91apache2

/etc/rc5.d/S91apache2

/etc/rc6.d/K09apache2

> sudo find /etc/rc* -iname "*tomcat*"

/etc/rc0.d/K85tomcat

/etc/rc1.d/K85tomcat

/etc/rc2.d/S25tomcat

/etc/rc3.d/S25tomcat

/etc/rc4.d/S25tomcat

/etc/rc5.d/S25tomcat

/etc/rc6.d/K85tomcat

> sudo find /etc/rc* -iname "*glassfish*"

/etc/rc0.d/K84glassfish

/etc/rc1.d/K84glassfish

/etc/rc2.d/S26glassfish

/etc/rc3.d/S26glassfish

/etc/rc4.d/S26glassfish

/etc/rc5.d/S26glassfish

/etc/rc6.d/K84glassfish

right now its happening tomcat and glassfish start after i login

which takes few minutes to load

not allowing me normal work on PC

Wish to fix that

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking at the wrong place. Take a look at upstart. Sysvinit has been replaced by upstart in Ubuntu. The old init scripts still work but a lot of packages use the new startup system. Take a look at [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto).